# JS: Shorthand return destructured await object

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to create something like the second function, without assigning the destructured object first?

EDITED: added longURL

```js
const get = async () => {
  const { body: { shortURL, longURL } } = await got(options)
  return {shortURL, longURL}
}

const getShorthand = async () => (
  { body: { shortURL, longURL } } = await got(options)
)
```

UPDATE:

Clarified for highlighting where I think it might make sense for readability:

```js
const getURLs = async () => {
  const {
    body: {
      shortURL,
      longURL,
      iOSLink,
      androidLink,
      macOSLink,
      windowsLink,
      ubuntuLink,
    }
  } = await got(options)

  return {
    shortURL,
    longURL,
    iOSLink,
    androidLink,
    macOSLink,
    windowsLink,
    ubuntuLink,
  }
}

const getURLsShorthand = async () => (
  {
    body: {
      shortURL, 
      longURL, 
      iOSLink, 
      androidLink, 
      macOSLink, 
      windowsLink, 
      ubuntuLink,
    }
  } = await got(options)
)
```

Comment: Concentrate on making your code legible and maintainable, not fitting into one line.

Comment: True, just wondered, for some cases where it might be cleaner. In this case I agree it does little to nothing to help. Just thought to ask now that it occurred to me, that I don't know how this could be achieved, if you only want to send back a limited set of the results.

Comment: With the updated code, I believe it might help with readability, when you want to return a limited set of the body, without letting callers read more. Mainly for a large subset, as the properties would have to be listed twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
const getShorthand = async () => (await got(options)).body.shortURL;
```

but if you need more, just return the `body` and destructure later.

```
const getShorthand = async () => (await got(options)).body;
const {shortURL, longURL} = await getShorthand();
```

Comment: Thanks! Of course. Is there a way to return a limited set of the body?

Comment: `shortURL` **is** already a limited set of the `body`

Comment: Yep, meant if if I wanted to limit it to shortURL and longURL, to prevent the caller from reading more. I added longURL in an edit after your comment.

Comment: then you destructure in the callback and return an object with only those two properties ... there's no other way around, and also it's not an issue at all, not sure why you wanted to avoid the destructuring in the first place, at this point

Comment: To avoid other functions from reading properties of an object, they should not read. Mainly to avoid bugs later on. If a subset of 10 properties are returned, it would result in those 10 properties being listed twice, if I'm thinking straight.

Comment: it doesn't make sense. your *first* example is how you obtain what you are after. Nobody can read anything in there, there are two destructured properties nobody can interfere with, and you return a literal with only those two properties. Nothing can change that, nothing can read anything.

Comment: Yep the first examples work, but in cases with many properties, I do think an implementation like the last one would make sense, if it was possible in JavaScript. But it might just be me.

Comment: You’re right, my thoughts made no sense. But I still believe the ability to assign the values to the returned object, like constants would be useable. In destructuring the constants are of course separated, whereas the return object needs to be a single object. But I still think the shorthand notation fits other JavaScript notation.